# Changing values in a specific cell based on other cell/row inputs

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm fairly new to formulas and excel but this is one of the problems I have encountered.

I have been using 2 conditional formatting formulas as follows

1. `=INDIRECT("I"&ROW())="Del"`
2. `=INDIRECT("I"&ROW())="Sum"`

Where the first formula simply highlights the row grey if del is in the I column of that row, is there also a way of making it change say the K column to 0 if column H in that row is 0?

And for the second formula which also highlights the row another color based on sum input in the given column of that row, is it also possible to change K column of that row to match the value of H column of the given row.

I know they would be similar but I needed to make it so formula one would only zero the K column in the given row if I column had "del" and H column of the row had Zero.

And for the second formula the values would only change in column k of the given row if "sum" was in the I column. Anything else needs to stay unformatted unless these changes are implemented.

I am unable to add a formula the the cells in question as these are overwritten with an button clicked event which inputs data into this field.

any information is appreciated, formula or VBA.

Comment: Conditional formatting can only change the formatting of cells; it cannot change the formulas or values. Since the values in K are regularly overwritten, you can't rely on a worksheet formula either. You need a VBA solution.

Comment: As of now, how is the cell in Col K populated? Is it empty? Does it have any default data? Does it have any formulas?

Comment: There is no data at this time but it is generally populated from entering data elsewhere on the worksheet and clicking on a button which populates this row.

Comment: @user1361149 why not change the macro that is run after clicking the button then??

Answer (score 1):

a) use `=$I2="Del"` instead of INDIRECT (where `2` is the first row of the range your conditional format applies to, e.g. *=$A$2:$Z$9999*, or the row of the firstly selected cell of the range when you are inserting the conditional format)

b) if you can use a new column that won't be overwritten, the formula in this new column can be:

```
=if(and(I2="Del";H2=0);0;if(I2="Sum";H2;K2))
```

P.S.: use `,` instead of `;` if your Windows > Control Panel > Region and Language > Additional settings... > List separator is set to a comma

Comment: Thanks, as stated this field will alway be filled with data, as the row is populated from another part of the worksheet from data input and then a button being clicked this then populates said row. and this repeats for 1 - say 500 rows. The problem is 2 of the end columns need to be locked, which is why i need the values to change when the cell in questions change. sorry if Im not expaining this clearly

Answer (score 0):

Just adjust the Offset accordingly to change the column(s) you want.

```
Dim firstCell As Range
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim lastrow As Long

With ActiveSheet

    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    With Range("H2:H" & lastrow)

        Set FoundCell = .Find(What:="3")
        Set firstCell = FoundCell
        Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
            '.offset(0,-1) would be the same row in Column "G"
            FoundCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = 0
            'if you wanted to assign the same value then do this:
            '  FoundCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = FoundCell.Value
            Set FoundCell = .FindNext(FoundCell)
            If FoundCell.Address = firstCell.Address Then
              Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End With
```